# LWJGL Use fbo texture as input to a shader

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, minecraft-forge

I am attempting to use a shader to copy at texture to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` of the framebuffer object. I have used a minecraft-forge coremod to render the game (with a few changes) to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`. This step is working because I can then use `glBlitFramebuffer` to copy it to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` (Everything in `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` is rendered to the screen by Minecraft).

I have created a shader that accepts a texture as input and draws the texture with modifications. When I change the bound texture (line ending in `//FIXME`) I get game textures drawn to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` with the modifications.

When I try to render the texture I created, I just get a black screen. I have tried using a separate framebuffer object to hold the texture, and unbinding the texture from the framebuffer object. Both of these attempts resulted in the same black screen.

How can I use a shader to render my texture to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`?

```
    //<render to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1>

    //Use shader
    GL20.glUseProgram(shader.getShaderProgram());

    //Setup view
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    //Render
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, shader.getVbo());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL11.GL_BYTE, false, 0, 0L);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); //FIXME
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //Reset view
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();

    //Reset shader
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);

    //<draw HUD>
    //<render to screen>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using deprecated OpenGL and you should skip it unless you really need it.

Second, you may want to use [this sample](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_320/fbo/Gl_320_fbo_blit.java) as inspiration. It has a `glBlitFramebuffer` between `RENDER` and `RESOLVE` fbo, but this doesn't have interest for you. You should look instead at the [*pass 2*](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_320/fbo/Gl_320_fbo_blit.java#L283), where it:

- binds the default fbo
- sets the viewport
- clear the color buffer
- set the transformation matrix
- binds the texture it is going to render
- binds the vao
- and finally it renders using `glDrawArraysInstanced` but you just use `glDrawArrays` instead